# Find frequency of relationships of tags in lists (pairwise correlation?)

Tags: python, list, combinations, counter, data-analysis

I have some lists of tags for images. I want to find out which tags seem to be related:

```
l1 = ["cat", "toe", "man"]
l2 = ["cat", "toe", "ice"]
l3 = ["cat", "hat", "bed"]
```

In this (simple) example obviously, "cat" and "toe" seem related, because they appear two times (l1, l2).

How can this be computed? With a result like: cat & toe: 2. I have a clue that I am asking for "pairwise correlation" but resources to that kind of analysis are too complicated for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` with `frozenset` and `itertools.combinations` to form a dictionary of pairwise counts.

Variations are possible. For example, you can use `collections.Counter` with sorted `tuple` instead, but fundamentally the same idea.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

dd = defaultdict(int)

L1 = ["cat", "toe", "man"]
L2 = ["cat", "toe", "ice"]
L3 = ["cat", "hat", "bed"]

for L in [L1, L2, L3]:
    for pair in map(frozenset, (combinations(L, 2))):
        dd[pair] += 1
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(int,
            {frozenset({'cat', 'toe'}): 2,
             frozenset({'cat', 'man'}): 1,
             frozenset({'man', 'toe'}): 1,
             frozenset({'cat', 'ice'}): 1,
             frozenset({'ice', 'toe'}): 1,
             frozenset({'cat', 'hat'}): 1,
             frozenset({'bed', 'cat'}): 1,
             frozenset({'bed', 'hat'}): 1})
```

Comment: Thanks! And I can escalate this to triples with combinations(L, 3)! Cool.

Comment: Can it be done without frozen set? Where would we go from `l = [list(combinations(i, 2)) for i in l4]` , `l4` being list of the 3 lists

Comment: You need hashable keys, lists won't work. As I mentioned instead of `frozenset` you can use `tuple` [provided it's sorted].

Comment: One more thinggggg, Is it possible to do a direct count verse a incremental count

Comment: @vash_the_stampede, SO isn't a forum. I suggest you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have one.

Comment: roger that , will do

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a DataFrame with an indicator variable for each unique word as the columns:

```
from itertools import chain
all_tags = set(chain.from_iterable([l1, l2, l3]))
d = pd.DataFrame([{k: 1 if k in l else 0 for k in all_tags} for l in [l1, l2, l3]])
print(d)
#   bed  cat  hat  ice  man  toe
#0    0    1    0    0    1    1
#1    0    1    0    1    0    1
#2    1    1    1    0    0    0
```

Now you can transpose this matrix and dot it with itself to get the pairwise counts:

```
pairwise_counts = d.T.dot(d)
print(pairwise_counts)
#     bed  cat  hat  ice  man  toe
#bed    1    1    1    0    0    0
#cat    1    3    1    1    1    2
#hat    1    1    1    0    0    0
#ice    0    1    0    1    0    1
#man    0    1    0    0    1    1
#toe    0    2    0    1    1    2
```

The diagonal of this matrix is the number of times each word appears in your data.

If you wanted the pairwise count of any two strings, for example `"cat"` and "`toe`", you can do:

```
print(pairwise_counts.loc["cat", "toe"])
#2
```

Since this matrix is symmetric, you would get the same answer for:

```
print(pairwise_counts.loc["toe", "cat"])
#2
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good too! Will it also work for triples etc? (I know, I did not ask for that.)

Comment: @j____r___ no, this is only for pairwise. You may want to research something called frequent itemsets or association rule learning